# Error Code 0x800700a1 when trying to add registry key through GPO

Tags: windows-7, group-policy, windows-registry

I'm trying to add a new group policy to our domain so that images are automatically sent with emails in Outlook 2013. So I created the following GPO:

[image: Screenshot of GPO properties]

This policy doesn't have any effect though. When I run `gpupdate` and then `gpresult`, the report will tell me the following regarding the policy:

> Result: Failure (Error Code: 0x800700a1)

What's the problem with the policy?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The **Key Path** set in the GPO must not start with a `\`. Removing it will make the policy apply correctly.